# how to correctly call API so it is used everywhere in the app in react, redux, regardless of route

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am using react and redux. My main component calls an api and stores it in the redux store. This is essentially a list of JSON: `[{id: 1, name: Sarah}, {id:2, name: Tom}]`

I have a new route that renders a new component that depends on the list of JSON above, with the url: `/detail/:id`

Instead of calling the API again, I fetch it from my redux store.

If a user goes to `mydomain.com`, the app works fine because the first thing it'll do is call the API and store it to use throughout the app.

The problem is that if a user directly does to `mydomain.com/detail/1`, my app will get the list from the redux store, which is empty, and will display an error message. This is because the main component is the one that handles the API calls and stores it in the redux store. However the main component isn't even rendered here so no API is executed and therefore my redux store is empty.

How can I ensure that these essential APIs are executed every time a user visits the app, regardless of which route, without having every component call the API

Answer (score 0):

I have 3 suggestions:

1. Use `redux-saga`, fetch your data in saga on some action call and call this action from wherever you need.
2. You can place both your pages in one parent which will preload data and only after them will display an actual page (if you are using react-router, for example, it will be a really easy task to do)
3. You can create some wrapper component which will load the data and then render your content. Difference with 2nd suggestion is that you will use it only for pages that need those data to be preloaded instead of preloading it globally